# While using a single quote in a string in shell with Ruby I get sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: ruby, bash

This works fine in Ruby, and it should work:

`puts 'don\'t'`

But I want to run the same in BASH with Ruby:

`%x(echo 'don\'t')`

I get this error:
`sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching`''`

Same error occurs with ``, `system()`, `Open3`

My actual code snippet:

```
require 'open3'

module XdoTool
    BIN = 'xdotool'
    EXEC = ::ENV['PATH'].split(::File::PATH_SEPARATOR).map { |path| ::File.join(path, BIN) if ::File.executable?(::File.join(path, BIN)) }.compact.last
    raise RuntimeError, "No #{BIN} found in the exported paths. Please make sure you have #{BIN} installed" unless EXEC

    class << self
        def type(str)
            Open3.capture2("#{EXEC} type --delay 0 '#{str = str.gsub("'", '\'')}'")
            str
        end
    end
end

# Types the quoted text anywhere.
XdoTool.type("What is the reason of the error?")


# sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
# sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
XdoTool.type("What's the reason of the error?")
```

Please do note that the str can have anything. It can contain alphanumeric characters, symbols, emojis, or combination of all these things. How can I get around the problem with quotes here?

Comment: Try putting in double quotes `echo "don\'t"`. Bash does not handle escaped single quotes inside a set of single quotes

Comment: I can't. The str parameter could have double quotes as well. It depends on the user. Using "" will prevent using " inside.

Comment: I want to escape the quote. But for some strange reason, this works in sh or BASH, but doesn't work with sh from Ruby! I can't find out the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell, you simply cannot include a single quote inside a single-quoted string. It has to be in a double-quoted string. That means, if you want an argument that contains *both*, you need to concatenate separately quoted stings together.

```
echo 'He said "I can'"'"t'"'
```

or escape the double quotes inside a double-quoted string

```
echo "He said \"I can't\""
```

(Some shells provide yet another form of quoting that *can* contain an escaped single quote, namely `$'He said "I can\'t"'`. However, that's an extension to the POSIX standard that you can't assume is supported by the
shell Ruby will use to execute your command.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
I have now done this:
`str = str.gsub('"', ("\\\""))`
`Open3.capture2("#{EXEC} type --delay 0 \"#{str}\"")`
And it now works!

Comment: I also have to `str = str.gsub('"', ("\\\"")).gsub('$', '\$')` because otherwise if my argument goes like '$HOME' it types `/home/sourav`

Comment: You may be better off using the form of `capture2` that takes the command name and its arguments as a list, rather than a single string to be parsed by the shell. Something like `capture2("#{EXEC}", "type", "--delay", "0", "#{str}")` (my knowledge of Ruby is shaky), so that you don't need to escape any quotes ahead of time.

Comment: That last comment (without the extra string interpolation: `Open3.capture2(EXEC, 'type', '--delay', '0', str)`) really should be your answer. There's no need whatsoever to be messing around with escaping and shells here.